# Not able to get absolute path from virtual machine if I put in Function from a Mapped Network Drive

Tags: vbscript

Scenario:
I am running my VBScript in 'Test complete' which is a Automation Testing Tool from a Virtual Machine.
My scripts are residing in the Folder `E:\TC from VM\TC` (in physical Machine).
I have mapped my VM to this shared folder, so from VM my directory structure is: `Z:\E\TC from VM\TC`.

If I put the code here - then it displays the path correctly - but if I put this code in a function and call the function it displays a different path. WHY, and how I can rectify it?

```
Dim fso, ShowAbsolutePath, objFile, GetParentDir
Dim strFile : strFile = "..\..\Variables.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
ShowAbsolutePath = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(strFile)
Log.Message("The File is:"&ShowAbsolutePath)
GetParentDir = fso.GetParentFolderName(ShowAbsolutePath)
Log.Message("The parent directory of the File is:"&GetParentDir)
Set objFile = fso.GetFile(ShowAbsolutePath)
```

Output :

```
The File is:Z:\E\TC from VM\TC\Variables.txt
The parent directory of the File is:Z:\E\TC from VM\TC
```

Output (if I put this code in function and then call the function):

```
The File is:Z:\E\TC from VM\TC\MMSDemo\MMSDemo
The parent directory of the File is:Z:\E\TC from VM\TC\MMSDemo
```

Why the difference?
I am just passing to the function the variable `strFile` where `strFile = "..\..\Variables.txt"`.

Comment: Just a wild guess, but my vbs ide allows to test code without saving. If you would change something there and run the code without saving it would still run, but because of not saving it would really be a temp file from a different location. With a relative path like you are using it if yours behaves similar and you didn't save the function changes it could lead to such behaviour

Comment: You need to show the code that is *not* working, including how it's called.

Answer (score 0):

.GetAbsolutePathName() combines the current directory with the relative path given as parameter without regard to existence of files or folders:

```
>> WSCript.Echo goFS.GetAbsolutePathName("..\nosuchdir\nosuchfile.txt")
>>
E:\trials\SoTrials\answers\27749208\nosuchdir\nosuchfile.txt
```

So the given parameter must be part of the result. If you get

```
The File is:Z:\E\TC from VM\TC\MMSDemo\MMSDemo
The parent directory of the File is:Z:\E\TC from VM\TC\MMSDemo
```

then .GetAbsolutePathName() was **not** called with "....\Variables.txt", but with an empty value/string. Do you use "Option Explicit"?